# нужно ли дополнительное оборудование для работы метода АОА?

Tags: wifi, геолокация

ситуация: мы хотим найти местоположение пользователей которые используют приложение .Территория где должна выполняться позиционирование нам не известно и у нас нет заранее приготовленной инфраструктуры и мы можем использовать лишь существующую инфраструктуру которая будет под рукой то есть точки доступов WI FI (например которые данный момент доступны у пользователя)  . В таком случай можно ли применить метод позиционирования AOA и может ли метод AOA работать с обычными точками доступов Wi Fi или нужны дополнительное оборудование ?

Answer (score 0):

Я экспериментировал с этим. Уровень сигнала уменьшается с удалением от точки по логарифмическому закону для уровня сигнала и линейно для сектора.

Предел чувствительности обычных точек доступа около -80 дБ что соответствует 120 метрам, точность 1дБ на этом расстоянии примерно ±25 метров.

На небольших расстояниях точность около полуметра, но уровень сигнала очень сильно гуляет ±5 дБ максимум но обычно меньше, что дает возможность позиционировать с точностью до метра если в радиусе 10 метров есть 3-4 точки доступа вайфай.

Для метода АОА не подойдут точки доступа siso и mimo. Потому что радиомодуль не передает данные о секторе клиента. Даже со стеком потому как софтовые часы плавают очень сильно, а данные с ядра поступают не в реальном времени.

Нужна mumimo точка доступа. А там проблема со снятием данных. Инструментов готовых почти нет.